# Distribution of $Y$ if $Y=X$ if $|X|\leq c$ and $Y=-X$ if $|X|>c$, $X\in N(0,1)$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X\in N(0,1)$, and $c\geq 0$.

$Y$ is defined as

$Y=\begin{cases}X & \text{for}\quad |X|\leq c,\\
-X&\text{for}\quad |X|>c.\end{cases}$

What is the distribution of $Y$? I would guess it has a normal distribution given that

$X\overset{d}{=} -X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is $N(0,1)$: $P(Y \leq y)= P(X \leq y, |X| \leq c)+P(-X \leq y, |X| > c)$ In the second term use the  fact that $-X$ has the same distribution as $X$ to see that $P(Y \leq y)= P(X \leq y, |X| \leq c)+P(X \leq y, |X| > c)=P(X  \leq c)$$