# Problem with module

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

Knowing that…

- $Y:=\left\{\begin{matrix} X & if & |X|<a\\ -X & if & |X| \geq a \end{matrix}\right.$;
- $X \sim N(0,1)$;
- $a>0$;

…and obviously $|X|:=\left\{\begin{matrix}
X & if & X \geq 0\\ 
-X & if & X <0
\end{matrix}\right.$, I have to prove that $Y$ is normal.

I got to get there myself, but I'm stuck how to broach the problem. Can you give me a hint to go on?

---

EDIT:

Looking the hints below I wrote:

$F_Y(y)=\mathbb{P}(Y \leq y)=\mathbb{P}([|X|<a  \cap X \geq 0] \cup[|X| \geq a \cap X<0])=\mathbb{P}(|X|<a \cap X \geq 0) + \mathbb{P}(|X| \geq a \cap X<0)=\mathbb{P}(-a<X<a \cap X \geq 0)+\mathbb{P}(-a \geq X \geq a \cap X<0)=2\mathbb{P}(0<X<a \cap X \geq 0)+\underbrace{2\mathbb{P}(0 \geq X \geq a \cap X<0)}_{=0}=2\mathbb{P}(0<X<a \cap X \geq 0)=2\mathbb{P}(0<X<a)=2[\mathbb{P}(X<a)-\mathbb{P}(X<0)]=2[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{a}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{0}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx]$

Obviously it's about two CDF of $X$, so I can conclude that $Y$ is normal. Is it correct?

Comment: Hint: Try computing the CDF defined by $F_Y(y)=P(Y\leq y)$. This can be split into three cases, either $y\in(-\infty,-a]$ or $y\in(-a,a)$ or $y\in[a,\infty)$.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent#An_asymmetric_example.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Thanks for your hint. Could you just look at my edit?

Comment: "Problem with module" is a slightly misleading title, inasmuch as "module" has a specific technical meaning in a mathematical context.  In this case, it's clear that isn't intended, but since vague titles are frowned on anyway, perhaps you can change it to a more descriptive title?

Comment: You have to show $P(Y\le y)=P(X\le y)$ for every real $y$. As shown in the wiki link, you can directly say $P(Y\le y)=P(Y\le y, |X|<a)+P(Y\le y, |X|\ge a)$. The remaining calculation can be finished in a couple of lines.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Thanks again. So where I wrong in the passages?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3688871/321264